# 'AndroidAccessory' does not name a type error when I try to verify Hello World sketch from Beginning Android ADK with Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, adk, accessory

So I've been working through the book and now I find myself stuck at page 49-50 trying to establish the first hint of communication between Android and my MEGA ADK 2560 R3 board.
I should include that I have downloaded the updated USB host shield 2.0 and renamed it as USB_HOST_20, and that's how I got as far as I did.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <max3421e.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>



#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

AndroidAccessory acc("Google,Inc.","ExtendHelloWorld","Test","1.0","http://www.android.com");

char hello[ARRAY_SIZE] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','!'};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(115200);
acc.powerOn();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 
  if (acc.isConnected()){
    for(int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++) {
      Serial.print(hello[x]);
      delay(250);
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(250);
  }
}
```

My error returns:

```
ExtendHelloWorld:10: error: 'AndroidAccessory' does not name a type
ExtendHelloWorld.ino: In function 'void setup()':
ExtendHelloWorld:17: error: 'acc' was not declared in this scope
ExtendHelloWorld.ino: In function 'void loop()':
ExtendHelloWorld:22: error: 'acc' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so, here is what I did. After searching for a LONG time on the interwebs, I found that there was an updated version of Android Accessory which made all my compiling errors go away. The file name is called "USBHOST2_0_Androidaccessory.zip" After replacing the original Android Accessory file with these two, I plugged everything up.

Unfortunately, now I get an error on the serial monitor of

```
AndroidAcessory powerOn: USB Initialization failed...HALTED!
```